# Cannot connect to Win10 IoT with Remote Client?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, powershell, iot, windows-iot-core

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 3, and after much work, was able to get Windows 10 IoT Core running on it. To do so, I need to run [Windows 10 Iot Core Dashboard](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/iotdashboard) as an Administrator, because it would always fail to unpack the OS if you weren't running it as an admin. Once I got that running, I followed [Jasper's guide](http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2016/04/iot-enabling-windows-iot-remote-server-on-raspberry-pi/) to execute the appropriate commands via Powershell to start the RDP server. I then installed the [Iot Remote Client](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/windows-iot-remote-client/9nblggh5mnxz) from the Microsoft Store and here's where it's been interesting.

The first couple of times I used the Remote Client, it actually worked! I could RDP into my Pi without issue, save a little lag here and there. However, at some point and for no discernible reason, that stopped working. I know that the NanoRDP client is still running on the Pi, because I can verify that in Powershell, and also by the fact that the device is discoverable in the Remote Client (it is ordinarily not discoverable when the RDP client isn't running).

[image: remote client]

Unfortunately, now it consistently times out whenever I hit Connect from the Remote Client.

[image: timed out]

I even tried starting the whole process over again, by re-flashing my MicroSD card and starting anew. But the Remote Client times out every time. Has anyone else dealt with this? Any advice on why this isn't working?